# In Javascript, how can I prevent the second function from running unless the first function has been invoked?

Tags: javascript, function, invoke

This has probably been covered before, but what I'm seeing online is confusing, or at least too advanced for a beginner like myself. Here's an example....

```
var funcA = function() {
  alert("Button A has been pressed");
};
var funcB = function() {
  if (funcA === false){
    alert("press Button A");
  }
  else{
    alert("Button B has been pressed");
  }
};

var buttonA = document.getElementById('button1');
buttonA.onclick = funcA;
var buttonB = document.getElementById('button2');
buttonB.onclick = funcB;
```

If I click on Button A or Button B in any order, they work; but I don't want Button B to work unless Button A has been clicked first. With the code I have now, the if statement in funcB never runs, but the else statement always runs.

Comment: just use a boolean flag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might create a variable that would effectively function as a switch that you hit when you run function A. :

```js
var funcAPressed = false;

var funcA = function() {
  alert("Button A has been pressed");
  funcAPressed = true;
};
var funcB = function() {
  if (funcAPressed === false){
    alert("press Button A");
  }
  else{
    alert("Button B has been pressed");
  }
};

var buttonA = document.getElementById('button1');
buttonA.onclick = funcA;
var buttonB = document.getElementById('button2');
buttonB.onclick = funcB;
```

Comment: I ended up going with this suggestion. I'm basically saying that var funcAPressed = false. This is how it will be unless declared otherwise. When funcA runs, it now declares funcAPressed as true.

If funcAPressed is false, which is it by default, the if statement in funcB runs. But if funcAPressed becomes true, which happens after funcA is invoked, the else statement in func B runs.

Answer (score 0):

The code block inside the following `if` statement will never run because `funcA` is not a boolean, it is a function that has no return value.

```
if (funcA === false){
    alert("press Button A");
}
```

What you can do however is just declare a boolean that serves as a flag, like so:

```js
(function() {

  let called = false;

  var funcA = function() {
    called = true;
    alert("Button A has been pressed");
  };
  var funcB = function() {
    if (!called) {
      alert("press Button A");
    } else {
      alert("Button B has been pressed");
    }
  };

  var buttonA = document.getElementById('button1');
  buttonA.onclick = funcA;
  var buttonB = document.getElementById('button2');
  buttonB.onclick = funcB;

})();
```

```html
<button id="button1">button 1</button>
<button id="button2">button 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change Button B's behavior in the click handler of button A:

```js
document.getElementById('a').onclick = () => {
   alert("Button A has been pressed");
   document.getElementById('b').onclick = () => {alert("Button B has been pressed") };
}       
document.getElementById('b').onclick = () => { alert("press Button A") };
```

```html
<button id="a">a</button>
<button id="b">b</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be dirty but can work `

```js
var count = 0;
function funcA(){
count =  1;
}
function funcB(){
if(count == 1){
alert("OKAy!")
}else{
alert("Press Button A");
}
}
```

```html
<button id="a" onclick="funcA();">A</button>
<button id= "b" onclick="funcB();">B</button>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already got the answer but just to add that when you do:

```
var funcA = function() {
  alert("Button A has been pressed");
}
```

And later check:

```
if (funcA === false){
    alert("press Button A");
}
```

Then funcA will not be false. The reason is that you have assigned a function object to funcA variable and hence it is truthy. It doesn't represent the fact that button1 has been pressed earlier or not. Javascript is different from other classical languages and hence in javascript function can be assigned to a variable. Hope it helps you learn the language better!

Comment: I'm not going to vote this answer down, but could you explain the problem this answer is written to address? From my own reading the OP wants to call/enable `funcB()` only after `funcA()` has been called and run, which this answer doesn't seem to address.

Comment: What I am trying to explain here is that why his expectation in the code he wrote was wrong. This is in the hope that it helps him in understanding the root cause of the problem.

Comment: I get what you're saying, funcA can't be false since I declared and defined it to a variable..hence it exists..right?

I ended up going with Jeremy's suggestion, it's the simplest one and something I can understand:

I'm declaring var funcAPressed = false into the global scope. 
Therefore funcAPressed will always be false unless otherwise stated. But when funcA is invoked, funcAPressed = true happens...making that true. And the if Statement in funcB only runs if funcAPressed = false.

I'm probably explaining it all wrong, but it's something I understand and was able to implement.